# Naming unit test methods of overloads in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, naming-conventions

What is the most accepted way to name a unit test method when the target has overloads. Consider these methods:

```
doSomething();
doSomething(String);
```

How would you name the corresponding test methods? Would this be the most accepted way?

```
testDoSomething();
testDoSomethingString();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do whatever makes things more readable for you and your co-workers, if any. I think it depends on what your other tests for that class are, but based on those two methods, here is what I would do:

Test methods that test doSomething():

- doSomething_void_success (this would be some test that tests a successful path)
- doSomething_void_fail (this would be some test that tests an incorrect path)
- doSomething_void_someOtherTest

Test methods that test doSomething(String):

- doSomething_String_success
- doSomething_String_fail
- doSomething_String_someOtherTest

I don't use the test prefix anymore, as JUnit 4 doesn't require it. I just use the @Test annotation

Comment: +1 This answers sums up the main ideas from all the answers so far.

Answer (score 4):

There is no single "most accepted way" - pick what you(r team) feel is most readable and clean.

I personally don't use the `test` prefix anymore, as it is not necessary since JUnit 4, and it degrades readability and searchability. I try to name my test methods after the scenarios they test. Which in your simplistic case could possibly be

```
doSomethingSuccessfully();
...
failsToDoSomethingWithAString();
...
doSomethingWithAStringAndFail();
```

Comment: I think they should all start with "doSomething" so that it's easy to see what method the test method is testing, and so that if you sort alphabetically (in the Outline window in Eclipse for example), all the "doSomething" tests will be together.

Comment: @dgrant, indeed, that's an important point, I just couldn't come up with a satisfying name for the failing test. Now I added one.

Comment: If you name your test methods basing yourself in the scenarios they test, maybe you are talking already about the behaviours of the methods you test, so you are doing BDD (Behaviour Driven Development).
I would like to invite you to take a look at a plugin I have developed for IntelliJ IDEA  (eclipse version exists too) that allows you to autogenerate test methods (with proper names) based in the behaviours of your test methods. You can take a look at a introduction at: http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=5847

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the matter of your dev environment conventions.

I prefer to use underscores, as it allows cleaner representations of methods under test.

I also, still use `test` prefix, though others pointed out that it's not required. I usually do this in order to separate actual tests from some helper methods that may be in the test class.

So, in your case, I would do

```
test_doSomething
test_doSomething_String
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the desired behaviours to name your test methods, for example:

```
/**
*
* @return
* @should say hello, and nothing more that that
*/
String sayHello();
}
```

Would create a test method like this one:

```
@Test
public void sayHello_shouldSayHelloAndNothingMoreThatThat() throws Exception {
//TODO auto-generated
Assert.fail("Not yet implemented");
}
```

I have developed a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (Eclipse version exists too) for creating these test methods for you, you can find it here:

http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=5847